# unable to install mysqlclient using pip

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, centos7, mysql-connector

I tried to install mysqlclient and it's complaining abut mysql_config file not present. After reading the docs. I tried install `sudo yum install mariadb-devel` and `sudo yum install mysql-devel`. still I'm getting the same error. I'm using centos 7

```
sudo pip install mysqlclient
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
WARNING: The directory '/home/bramaraju/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
WARNING: The directory '/home/bramaraju/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Looking in indexes: https://security_automation:****@box.jfrog.io/box/api/pypi/Security-PyPi-Local/simple, https://security_automation:****@box.jfrog.io/box/api/pypi/box-pypi/simple, https://pypi.python.org/simple
Collecting mysqlclient
  Downloading https://box.jfrog.io/box/api/pypi/box-pypi/packages/packages/f8/9b/5db9a03e2088a87c26e3e4d4c7f7e8f4c2dbae610f9521cdfac15755a795/mysqlclient-1.4.5.tar.gz (86kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 5.3MB/s 
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python2 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-KrW_Ny/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-KrW_Ny/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-KrW_Ny/mysqlclient/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-KrW_Ny/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (12 lines):
    sh: mysql_config: command not found
    sh: mariadb_config: command not found
    sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-KrW_Ny/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 16, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 61, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 29, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (_mysql_config_path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

But while install mysql-devel. I'm getting bellow error. so installed using sudo yum install mysql-devel --skip-broken

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: zlib-devel-1.2.7-18.el7.x86_64 (cie-base)
           Requires: zlib = 1.2.7-18.el7
           Installed: lib64zlib1-1.2.8-7.1.mga5.x86_64 (@security-rpm-local-thirdparty)
               zlib = 1.2.8-7.1.mga5
           Available: zlib-1.2.7-18.el7.i686 (cie-base)
               zlib = 1.2.7-18.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 0):

You have zlib from from the repo @security-rpm-local-thirdparty which is conflicting. Having such a package will conflict with a lot of the Centos/RHEL packages you wish to install.

Recommend removing lib64zlib1/1.2.8-7.1.mga5 and install the system zlib.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I installed pymysql which does not require mysql_config